# A bird to remember

Tags: riddle, animals

> Rotated around, I am still the same,
>   Reflected about, I am still the same,
>   In three other birds, you’ll find me each time,
>   What songbird am I? Last seen a while ago.
>   This is my message to you-ou-ou.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> ōʻō(OO) as in [Genus Moho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moho_%28genus%29)

Rotated around, I am still the same,

> OO is a palindrome.

Reflected about, I am still the same,

> OO rotated gives OO again.

In three other birds, you’ll find me each time,

> R**oo**k(previously wood), C**oo**t, L**oo**n middle of each.

What songbird am I? Last seen a while ago.

> Some of them were sold as song birds and are now extinct.

This is my message to you-ou-ou.

> Referring to either the o's or for the sound they produced.

Title

> They are extinct and hence being remembered.

Comment: The birds I know with 'tit' are blue tit, great tit and coal tit - more [here](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/bird-and-wildlife-guides/browse-bird-families/tits.aspx)

Comment: Fits very nicely! For the answer, the rotation is a 180 degrees half-turn, and I'm the middle of 3 other birds.

Comment: @Tom Oh, I thought I had it. Well, I have added another one. Hope that's better :-)

Comment: TechI - you have it now perfect. I thought this was pretty obscure, great explanations!

Comment: @Tom Took care of that!

Comment: It's found in a *lot* more than three birds, and more than once in some (e.g. blue-footed booby, boobook, bamboo woodpecker).

Comment: @Peter Taylor - Not in the middle :-)